# Meaning of but that

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of **but that** in the following sentence

> The situation now for the people (in Kashmir) is not good and not sustainable. This has to be improved for sure," said Ms. Merkel to a group of German journalists who travelled to Delhi for the visit. Officials said developments in Kashmir were not part of the bilateral delegation-level talks held at Hyderabad House, **but that** Ms. Merkel expected to hear from Prime Minister Narendra Modi on the government's road map for J&K during her formal dinner on November 1 night.

I looked up it’s meaning but didn’t find anything satisfactory.

Comment: ***but that** Ms. Merkel expected [blah blah]* is "shortened" from underlying *but **officials [also] said** that Ms. Merkel expected [blah blah]*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we remove the word "that":

> Officials said developments in Kashmir were not part of the bilateral
>   delegation-level talks held at Hyderabad House, but Ms. Merkel
>   expected to hear from Prime Minister Narendra Modi on the government's
>   road map for J&K during her formal dinner on November 1 night.

This reads as though the information about Ms. Merkel is coming from the narrator, as an exception to the fact that the officials said something, as though Ms. Merkel heard what the officials said but expected to hear from Prime Minister Narendra Modi anyway.

What the narrator is actually trying to express is that the officials stated that Ms. Merkel expected to hear from Prime Minister Narendra Modi, as an exception to the fact that developments in Kashmir were not part of the bilateral delegation-level talks held at Hyderabad House.

We could add another "that" into the statement to make it a bit clearer:

> Officials said **that** developments in Kashmir were not part of the
>   bilateral delegation-level talks held at Hyderabad House, but that Ms.
>   Merkel expected to hear from Prime Minister Narendra Modi on the
>   government's road map for J&K during her formal dinner on November 1
>   night.

When we use "that" like this, the "that" is referring to the reality/state of affairs expressed in the message that was communicated by the officials.

We don't need to use "that" in "officials said that", because it is obvious that we are referring to what the officials said, but if we were to omit the second "that", it sounds as though we are moving on from the officials' message, and presenting information as an exception to the entirety of what has been said in the sentence before.